# How can I avoid to retrieve the list of object associated as field into an Hibernate entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpql

I am absolutly new in Hibernate and I have the following doubt about the following problem:

I have an entity class mapping a table that contains as field another entity class mapping another table. I want to retrieve only the information related to the parent class and not the information related to the child one.

So I have this **Room** entity class representing a room of an accomodation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_accomodation_fk", nullable = false)
    private Accomodation accomodation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
    private RoomTipology roomTipology;

    @Column(name = "room_number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "room_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "room_description")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "max_people")
    private Integer maxPeople;

    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

As you can see this class contains this field that represent the child entity class and its **join** relationship with the **Room** entity class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
private RoomTipology roomTipology;
```

2) This is the **RoomTipology** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room_tipology")
public class RoomTipology implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tipology_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tipology_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Date timeStamp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private RoomRate roomRate;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

As you can see this entity class contains this field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
private List<Room> rooms;
```

that contains the list of **Room** objects associated to a specific **RoomTipology** object.

Then I have this **Spring Data JPA** repository class related to the **RoomTipology** entity class containing this query method:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomTipologyDAO extends JpaRepository<RoomTipology, Long> {

    @Query("from RoomTipology rt JOIN rt.rooms r WHERE r.id = :roomId")
    RoomTipology findByRoomId(@Param("roomId") Long roomId);

}
```

It works fine, but my problem is that every time that I call it, something like this:

```
RoomTipology roomTipologyById = roomTipologyDAO.findByRoomId(7L);
```

the returned object also contains the list of the rooms associated to this room's tipology, the **List rooms** field.

My problem is that when I call the previous **findByRoomId(@Param("roomId") Long roomId)** DAO method I only need to retrieve the information of a room's tipology and not also the entire list of associated room (I think that it will be to much heavy).

Can I avoid that the list of rooms associated to a RoomTipology object is retrieved? How can I do it?

Comment: OneToMany is lazy by default so it doesn't load all entities completely but proxy collection

Comment: @Argb32 what do you exactly mean? Can you explain me better this detail? :-)

Comment: I mean that in your case rooms will be a proxy collection and its entities will be loaded from database only when accessed from code. I recommend you to learn about lazy loading: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Query it from other side. `from Room r where r.id=?` this will load only needed Room with corresponding RoomTipology